# CRITICAL WORKER TIMEOUT in django cookie cutter with JsonResponse

Tags: django, gunicorn

I have the following logs

```
$ docker logs 1e5e704507c2
PostgreSQL is available

2198 static files copied to '/app/staticfiles', 6582 post-processed.
[2020-08-05 17:46:12 +0000] [10] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.0
[2020-08-05 17:46:12 +0000] [10] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (10)
[2020-08-05 17:46:12 +0000] [10] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2020-08-05 17:46:12 +0000] [17] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 17
[2020-08-05 17:46:12 +0000] [18] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 18
[2020-08-05 17:46:12 +0000] [19] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 19
[2020-08-05 17:46:12 +0000] [20] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 20
INFO 2020-08-05 17:48:21,763 views 18 140288548957512 meeting_approve:
[2020-08-05 17:48:51 +0000] [10] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:18)
[2020-08-05 17:48:51 +0000] [18] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 18)
[2020-08-05 17:48:52 +0000] [21] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 21
INFO 2020-08-05 17:52:06,252 views 17 140288548957512 meeting_approve:
[2020-08-05 17:52:36 +0000] [10] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:17)
[2020-08-05 17:52:36 +0000] [17] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 17)
[2020-08-05 17:52:36 +0000] [22] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 22
```

and this is my view

```
# views.py
def approve(request, pk):
    logger.info("meeting_approve:")
    try:
        logger.info("approve: query company api")
        r = requests.get(
            f"{foo}/bar",
            timeout=5,
        )
    except Timeout:
        messages.add_message(
            request, messages.WARNING, "Cannot connect to company api."
        )
        logger.warn(f"meeting_approve: Cannot connect to company api")
        return JsonResponse({"error": "Cannot connect to company api"}, status=500)
    logger.info(f"meeting_approve: check security {pk}")
    meeting = Meeting.objects.get(id=pk)
    logger.info(f"meeting_approve: check if blocked {meeting.company}")
```

Why does my JsonResponse timeout?

Answer (score 0):

The issue seemed to be any 5xx status would make the server timeout. Maybe this is because the api tries to send admins the stacktrace via email, and email is not configured on the server.

The workaround was to not use a 5xx status.

```
return JsonResponse({"error": "Cannot connect to company api"}, status=404)
```